# SQL SELECT Query

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Suppose I have a SQL table "Company" with three columns: "department_id", "employee", "job". Something like this:

```
DEPARTAMENT_ID | EMPLOYEE | JOB
--------------------------------------
1              | Mark     | President
1              | Robert   | Marketing Manager
1              | Rose     | Administration Assitant
2              | Anna     | Programmer
2              | Michael  | Programmer
2              | Celia    | Sales Manager
3              | Jhon     | Sales Manager
3              | Donna    | Programmer
3              | David    | Marketing Manager
```

I would like to write a query that returns the departments id where at least 50% of their jobs are the same.

Result i need in my example would be just:

```
DEPARTAMENT_ID |
--------------------------------------
2              |
```

How do I write this SQL query? I think i tried all kind of stuff but i dont get it :(.

Comment: Show what you have tried please!

Answer (score 4):

This is a bit tricky.  You need to compare the total number of people on a job in a department to the total number.  So, one method uses two aggregations:

```
select department_id
from (select department_id, count(*) as numemp
      from t
      group by department_id
     ) d join
     (select department_id, max(numemp) as numemp
      from (select department_id, job, count(*) as numemp
            from t
            group by department_id, job
           ) d
     group by department_id
    ) dj
    on d.numemp <= 2 * dj.numemp;
```

You might get duplicates if you have one department that is exactly split between two jobs.  In that case, use `select distinct`.

Comment: Omg. It works perfectly!!! :O Thank you so much!!! I was trying to do something like this but i use to complicate too much. Have a nice day!!